# Setting position of three.js object stored in an array

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-engine

i am trying to move my object on the x axis + 1 everytime my animate function is called but i kept running into the error that `cannot read property x of undefined`

so then everytime i added a mesh to the scene i added it to `sceneObjects` array

like this

```
addToGlScene(mesh, 'player')
```

using this function

```
    function addToGlScene(what, name, glow, storage){
        glScene.add(what)
        what.name = name
        sceneObjects.push(what)
        what.userData.glow = {glow: glow}
        what.userData.storage = {storage: storage}
        sceneObjects[name] = what
    }
```

so i try to change the objects position again using this method in my `animate()` function

```
    sceneObjects['player'].position
```

but i still get the same error

even when i `console.log(sceneObjects['player'])`
it shows all of this

```
    THREE.MorphAnimMesh {uuid: "42A8C528-F4E4-4317-9516-63B7B717BEF8", name: "player", type: "Mesh", parent: vd, children: Array(0), …}
    castShadow:
      false
      children:[]
      currentKeyframe:40
      direction:1
      directionBackwards:false
      drawMode:0
      duration:1000
      endKeyframe:163
      frustumCulled:true
      geometry:L {uuid: "5C675298-D5DD-4910-B98A-84D71A036636", name: "", type: "Geometry", vertices: Array(300), colors: Array(0), …}
      lastKeyframe:39
      layers:Wd {mask: 1}
      length:164
      material:Aa {uuid: "7E4FB381-61C2-4C33-8E08-C1997F94F0A4", name: "", type: "MeshBasicMaterial", fog: true, lights: false, …}
      matrix:O {elements: Array(16)}
      matrixAutoUpdate:true
      matrixWorld:O {elements: Array(16)}
      matrixWorldNeedsUpdate:false
      mirroredLoop:false
      morphTargetDictionary:{stand000î´: 0, stand001î´: 1, stand002î´: 2, stand003î´: 3, stand004î´: 4, …}
      morphTargetInfluences:(164) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.29446199999998723, 0.7055380000000128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …]
      name:"player"
      parent:vd {uuid: "C328C91A-D445-4E48-9C74-A15A4FA318AB", name: "", type: "Scene", parent: null, children: Array(13), …}
      position:p {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
      quaternion:ha {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, onChangeCallback: ƒ}
      receiveShadow:false
      renderOrder:0
      rotation:gb {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: ƒ}
      scale:p {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
      startKeyframe:0
      time:248.20450000000008
      type:"Mesh"
      up:p {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
      userData:{glow: {…}, storage: {…}}
      uuid:"42A8C528-F4E4-4317-9516-63B7B717BEF8"
      visible:true
      eulerOrder:(...)
      id:28
      modelViewMatrix:O {elements: Array(16)}
      normalMatrix:ma {elements: Array(9)}
      useQuaternion:(...)
      __proto__:ra
```

and here is my animate() funciton

```
        function animate() {
            if(typeof mesh != "undefined") mesh.updateAnimation(clock.getDelta() * 100);
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            glRenderer.render(glScene, camera);
            cssRenderer.render(cssScene, camera);
            if ( controlsEnabled === true ) {
                var time = performance.now();
                var delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;
                velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
                velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;
                velocity.y -= 9.8 * 40.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass
                direction.y = Number( flyDown) - Number(flyUp);
                direction.z = Number( moveForward ) - Number( moveBackward );
                direction.x = Number( moveLeft ) - Number( moveRight );
                direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions
                if (flyUp || flyDown) velocity.y -= direction.y * player.speed * delta;
                if ( moveForward || moveBackward ) velocity.z -= direction.z * player.speed * delta;
                if ( moveLeft || moveRight ) velocity.x -= direction.x * player.speed * delta;
                controls.getObject().translateX( velocity.x * delta );
                controls.getObject().translateY( velocity.y * delta );
                controls.getObject().translateZ( velocity.z * delta );
                if ( controls.getObject().position.y < player.heigth) {
                    velocity.y = 0;
                    controls.getObject().position.y = player.heigth;
                    canJump = true;
                }
                prevTime = time;
            }
            glRenderer.render( glScene, camera );
        }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It should be practical if you could add the code, structures... something we could look at :)

Comment: sorry about that i structured it :)

Comment: It is very difficult to identify the problem without knowing about the information like, where did you put `console.log(sceneObjects['player'])` and `sceneObjects['player'].position` ? Please show the code.

Comment: You aren't referencing `sceneObjects` in your animation function. `if(typeof mesh != "undefined")` will always skip, unless `mesh` is defined in a scope above `animate`. Before we go too far down this tear-down, I think you need to take a step back, create a minimal example that exhibits the same problem, and post it here so we can better debug the whole thing, rather than curated chunks of your code.

Comment: i just dont understand why doing `sceneObject['player'].position.x =+ 1` wont work if i can see it when i `console.log('sceneObject['player'] `and see all the objects info

Comment: Put `console.log(sceneObjects['player']);` in your animate function. If you can see the object, great. Then change it to `console.log(sceneObjects['player'].positon);` If it prints "undefined" then something is wrong somewhere else in your code.

Comment: i updated my question with more info, all the info that is relevant

Comment: height is spelt wrong twice in your animate function

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`sceneObjects['player'].position.x = newXValue;`

The `position` property is a [`Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3), from which you access the `x` property.

If `sceneObjects['player'].position` is undefined in the animate function, then something else is wrong.

Comment: This is correct. Updating the `Object3D`'s position value will move the object, but if it's saying position is undefined then the issue lies elsewhere in code and we need to see what the animation function looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself :) the reason that i kept getting the `undefined` error was because i was calling the `console.log(sceneObjects['player'].position)` in the animate function which fired as soon as the page was loaded and all the models weren't yet loaded in so i used the tree.js [Loading Manager](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) to only call the animate function after all the objects were loaded and it worked perfectly